# converting rpm file to debian fle

Tags: files, deb, rpm

Please any one give the solution for this whenever I try to convert the rpm file to deb file I always get this problem

```
error: /home/sumantakar/Documents/TestRPM.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest)
Error executing "LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} '/home/sumantakar/Documents/TestRPM.rpm'":  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 489
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks as if the .rpm is either not properly packaged or alien can not convert it.

As it is called "TestRPM.rpm" I am guessing not properly packaged.

In addition, if you have the source code, it is better to directly package it rather then convert it with alien.

Comment: but the problem is flash builder donot package it directly to deb file